# How do I migrate my tasks from Astrid to Google tasks?

Tags: google-tasks

I want to leave the [Astrid todo manager](http://astrid.com/) and move to [google tasks](https://mail.google.com/mail/help/tasks/). How do I migrate  my tasks out of Astrid and into Google tasks?

Answer (score 3):

Install the android app Gtasks before uninstalling Astrid. This app will ask if you want to import astrid tasks. Answer Yes and you are done ! GTasks syncs with Google tasks and your calendar. Took only 5 minutes to setup.

Answer (score 2):

From http://weloveastrid.com/help-user-guide-astrid-v3/backups-sync/:

> **[Sync To] Google Tasks [In Astrid]:**
>
> Press **Log In & Synchronize** to and select the Google account you’d
>   like to sync with.
>
> - **Status:** Displays whether you are syncing with Google Tasks and whether a sync was successful. It also provides useful stats such as
>     when you last synced your phone.
> - **Background Sync:** Set up the interval at which the phone should perform an automatic sync. You can have intervals as short as every
>     fifteen minutes or as long as every week.
> - **Sync on Save:** Option to sync individual tasks are they are saved on your phone.
> - **Log Out:** If you no longer want to sync to Google Tasks, simply log out.

This should get everything into Google Tasks before Yahoo! shuts Astrid down.